# Javascript ES6 better way to loop object and match with multiple nested object and return id

Tags: javascript, loops, object, ecmascript-6

I have it done but I think is not the best. I want to find out a better way (ES6) to loop multiple nested objects and met a condition and return id like below outcome (with and without)

I have two object variable:

```
let userid= 'samuel17786'

let questions = {
  "809992981": {
    id: '809992981',
    author: 'samuel17786',
    timestamp: 746716146716,
    optionOne: {
      userid: ['samuel17786','john6889'],
      food: 'salad',
    },
    optionTwo: {
      userid: [],
      food: 'sandwich'
    }
  },
  "740437039": {
    id: '740437039',
    author: 'john6889',
    timestamp: 436716146785,
    optionOne: {
      userid: ['petter334'],
      food: 'rice',
    },
    optionTwo: {
      userid: ['john6889'],
      food: 'spaghetti'
    }
  },
  "999937039": {
    id: '999937039',
    author: 'john6889',
    timestamp: 436444456785,
    optionOne: {
      userid: [],
      food: 'fish',
    },
    optionTwo: {
      userid: ['john6889','samuel17786'],
      food: 'shrimp'
    }
  },
}
```

the **outcome needs object id** that matches userid within **optionOne-->userid and optionTwo-->userid**

Need outcome like:

```
  with = ["809992981","999937039"]
  without = ["740437039"]
```

I have tried and its working (not the best way I think):

```
let without = [];
let with =[];
for (const key in questions) {

  //optional check for properties from prototype chain
  if (questions.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

      let existsInOne = Object.values(questions[key].optionOne.userid).includes(userid);


      let existsInTwo = Object.values(questions[key].optionTwo.userid).includes(userid);


      if(existsInOne || existsInTwo)
      {
        with.push(questions[key].id);
      }
      else if (!existsInOne && !existsInTwo) 
      {
        without.push(questions[key].id);
      }   
  }
}
```

I would like to know if there a better way to do this with ES6.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a single loop and sort the key to an object with boolean keys.

```js
let userid = 'samuel17786',
    questions = { 809992981: { id: '809992981', author: 'samuel17786', timestamp: 746716146716, optionOne: { userid: ['samuel17786', 'john6889'], food: 'salad' }, optionTwo: { userid: [], food: 'sandwich' } }, 740437039: { id: '740437039', author: 'john6889', timestamp: 436716146785, optionOne: { userid: ['petter334'], food: 'rice' }, optionTwo: { userid: ['john6889'], food: 'spaghetti' } }, 999937039: { id: '999937039', author: 'john6889', timestamp: 436444456785, optionOne: { userid: [], food: 'fish' }, optionTwo: { userid: ['john6889', 'samuel17786'], food: 'shrimp' } } },
    { true: with_, false: without } = Object.keys(questions).reduce((r, k) => {
        r[questions[k].author === userid].push(k);
        return r;
    }, { true: [], false: [] });

console.log(with_); // needs _ because with is a resereved word
console.log(without);
```

Comment: Hi Nina, first, I would like to thank you for helping me, but something I don't understand in your answer, the ".push(k)" , where does it push to (push to "with_" by default)? If I want to have a condition with optionOne and optionTwo, how would I push the questions[index] to the variable "without", thanks once again

Comment: @Sameul.T, it looks like i misread the question complete. please highlight in the question which array  goes into the result dicision and what reflects the wanted result.

Comment: I put console.log everywhere and see the logic of your code and now it is very clear. I make a tweak to the code to make the outcome I wanted, your code is done in a genius way. thank you once again :)